# Spyder isn't opening after update

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, spyder

I updated my Spyder to version `4.0.1` then this happens:

```
(base) C:\Users\Mehdi_2>conda run spyder

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", li
ne 3718, in main
    mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", li
ne 3559, in run_spyder
    main.setup()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", li
ne 1010, in setup
    from spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole.plugin import IPythonConsole
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole
\plugin.py", line 34, in <module>
    from zmq.ssh import tunnel as zmqtunnel
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\ssh\__init__.py", line 1,
 in <module>
    from zmq.ssh.tunnel import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\ssh\tunnel.py", line 26,
in <module>
    import paramiko
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\__init__.py", line 3
1, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line
70, in <module>
    from paramiko.sftp_client import SFTPClient
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", lin
e 43, in <module>
    from paramiko.sftp_file import SFTPFile
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_file.py", line
68
    self._close(async=True)
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried to use `spyder --reset`

I tried to reboot my system (I have 32-bit Win7)

But none of them actually works for me. What should I do?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please open the Anaconda prompt and run there `conda install -f paramiko`. That should fix the problem. If not, please run `conda remove paramiko` and try again.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Well It Didn't Help Me Either. And Also When I Use Second Command My Spyder Removed. :/ And Then I Reinstall It But It's Just Like Before.

Comment: Then please remove and reinstall Anaconda.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba That Was Tough But It Works For Me. Thanks :-)

Comment: Sorry but it's clear from your error that your installation was corrupted somehow.

Comment: When writing posts or comments here, please stick to sentence case. Title Case Like This Is Harder To Read and harder to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CarlosCordoba for his help in the comments. I uninstalled Anaconda then reinstalled it and now problem is solved.